# Slowdown when using ghc parallel strategies

Tags: multithreading, performance, haskell, parallel-processing, ghc

In order to learn about GHC's parallel strategies, I've written a simple particle simulator, that, given a particle's position, velocity, and acceleration, will project that particle's path forward.

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

-- Use phantom a to store axis.
newtype Pos a = Pos Double deriving Show
newtype Vel a = Vel Double deriving Show
newtype Acc a = Acc Double deriving Show
newtype TimeStep = TimeStep Double deriving Show

-- Phantom axis
data X
data Y

-- Position, velocity, acceleration for a particle.
data Particle = Particle (Pos X) (Pos Y) (Vel X) (Vel Y) (Acc X) (Acc Y) deriving (Show)

stepParticle :: TimeStep -> Particle -> Particle
stepParticle ts (Particle x y xv yv xa ya) =
  Particle x' y' xv' yv' xa' ya'
  where
    (x', xv', xa') = step ts x xv xa
    (y', yv', ya') = step ts y yv ya

-- Given a position, velocity, and accel, calculate the pos, vel, acc after
-- a given TimeStep.
step :: TimeStep -> Pos a -> Vel a -> Acc a -> (Pos a, Vel a, Acc a)
step (TimeStep ts) (Pos p) (Vel v) (Acc a) = (Pos p', Vel v', Acc a)
  where
    v' = ts * a + v
    p' = ts * v + p

-- Build a list of lazy infinite lists of a particles' travel
-- with each update a TimeStep apart. Evaluate each inner list in
-- parallel.
simulateParticlesPar :: TimeStep -> [Particle] -> [[Particle]]
simulateParticlesPar ts = withStrategy (parList (parBuffer 250 particleStrategy))
                          . fmap (simulateParticle ts)

-- Build a lazy infinite list of the particle's travel with each
-- update being a TimeStep apart.
simulateParticle :: TimeStep -> Particle -> [Particle]
simulateParticle ts m = m' : simulateParticle ts m'
  where
    m' = stepParticle ts m

particleStrategy :: Strategy Particle
particleStrategy (Particle (Pos x) (Pos y) (Vel xv) (Vel yv) (Acc xa) (Acc ya)) = do
  x' <-  rseq x
  y' <-  rseq y
  xv' <- rseq xv
  yv' <- rseq yv
  xa' <- rseq xa
  ya' <- rseq ya
  return $ Particle (Pos x') (Pos y') (Vel xv') (Vel yv') (Acc xa') (Acc ya')

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let world = replicate 100 (Particle (Pos 0) (Pos 0) (Vel 1) (Vel 1) (Acc 0) (Acc 0))
      ts = TimeStep 0.1
  print $ fmap (take 10000) (simulateParticlesPar ts world)
```

For each particle, I create a lazy infinite list projecting the particle's path into the future. I start out with 100 of these particles and project these all forward, my intention being to project each of these forward in parallel (roughly a spark per infinite list). If I project these lists forward long enough, I'd expect a significant speedup. Unfortunately, I see a slight slow down.

Compilation: `ghc phys.hs -rtsopts -threaded -eventlog -O2`

With 1 thread:

```
$ ./phys +RTS -N1 -sstderr -ls > /dev/null
  24,264,983,224 bytes allocated in the heap
     441,881,088 bytes copied during GC
       1,942,848 bytes maximum residency (104 sample(s))
          75,880 bytes maximum slop
               7 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     46820 colls,     0 par    0.82s    0.88s     0.0000s    0.0039s
  Gen  1       104 colls,     0 par    0.23s    0.23s     0.0022s    0.0037s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 1025000 (25 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 28680 GC'd, 996295 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    9.90s  ( 10.09s elapsed)
  GC      time    1.05s  (  1.11s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time   10.95s  ( 11.20s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,451,939,648 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  90.4% of total user, 88.4% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0
```

With 2 threads:

```
$ ./phys +RTS -N2 -sstderr -ls > /dev/null
  24,314,635,280 bytes allocated in the heap
     457,603,240 bytes copied during GC
       1,962,152 bytes maximum residency (104 sample(s))
         119,824 bytes maximum slop
               7 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     46555 colls, 46555 par    1.40s    0.85s     0.0000s    0.0048s
  Gen  1       104 colls,   103 par    0.42s    0.25s     0.0024s    0.0043s

  Parallel GC work balance: 16.85% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 6 (1 bound, 5 peak workers (5 total), using -N2)

  SPARKS: 1025000 (1023572 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 1367 GC'd, 61 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time   11.07s  ( 11.20s elapsed)
  GC      time    1.82s  (  1.10s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time   12.89s  ( 12.30s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,196,259,905 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  85.9% of total user, 90.0% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 9222
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 2393
```

I have an Intel i5 with 2 cores and 4 threads, and with -N4 it's 2x slower than -N1 (total time ~20 sec).

I've spent quite a bit of time trying different strategies, such as chunking the outer list (so each spark gets more than one stream to project forward) and using rpar for each field in particleStrategy, but I've yet to get any speed up at all.

Below is a zoomed in section of the eventlog under threadscope. As you can see, I'm getting almost no concurrency. Most of the work is being done by HEC0, with some activity from HEC1 interleaved in, but only one HEC is doing work at a time. This is pretty representative of all the strategies I've tried.
[image: -N2 under threadscope]

As a sanity check, I've run a few of the example programs from "Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell" and also see slow downs on these programs, even though I'm using the same params that give them significant speeds ups in the book! I'm beginning to think there's something wrong with my ghc.

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3
```

Installed from: https://ghcformacosx.github.io/

OS X 10.10.2

**Update:**

I've found this thread in the ghc tracker on an OS X threaded RTS performance regression: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7602. I'm hesitant to blame the compiler, but my -N4 outputs supports this hypothesis. The "parallel gc word balance" is terrible:

```
$ ./phys +RTS -N4 -sstderr -ls > /dev/null
  24,392,146,832 bytes allocated in the heap
     481,001,648 bytes copied during GC
       1,989,272 bytes maximum residency (104 sample(s))
         181,208 bytes maximum slop
               8 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     46555 colls, 46555 par    4.80s    1.98s     0.0000s    0.0055s
  Gen  1       104 colls,   103 par    0.99s    0.39s     0.0037s    0.0048s

  Parallel GC work balance: 7.59% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 10 (1 bound, 9 peak workers (9 total), using -N4)

  SPARKS: 1025000 (1023640 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 1331 GC'd, 29 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.01s elapsed)
  MUT     time   14.85s  ( 13.12s elapsed)
  GC      time    5.79s  (  2.36s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time   20.65s  ( 15.49s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,642,170,155 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  71.9% of total user, 95.9% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 61429
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 1
gen[1].sync: 617
```

On the other hand, I don't know if this explains my threadscope output, which shows a lack of any concurrency at all.

Comment: I played with this for a bit, and was able to get some decent concurrency, but I think it was still slower than single-threaded execution on 7.8.3. I would suggest using deepseq or the like to force evaluation, rather than `print`ing anything (this was *really* skewing runtime for me), and also start from a base with a `Particle` type with strict fields, compiling with `-funbox-strict-fields`

Comment: @jberryman Thanks for taking a look! I'll give these suggestions a try. Did printing the output skew the runtime even when the output was redirected to /dev/null?

Comment: Yes, although I'm sorry I wasn't very methodical so some of that might be off base